# How to render Iframe from JSON URL to React Component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, youtube-iframe-api

I am Trying to render YouTube Iframe from JSON file and Rendering into Child component. I Have a parent component which is loading card data from this JSON file.On the click of this card file I am rendering card data JSON value which is also has video url.When I click on card I open card data into new tab and I only gets Iframe box not a video preview like normal YouTube. What to do to fix it?

P.S My project Is React .Net Core.

CardData.tsx

```
const CardData = {
  "cards": [
    {
      "projectID": "00001",
      "projectName": "One tent system",
      "profileProjectImage": "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.br.catarse/uploads/project/uploaded_image/72644/project_thumb_large_capinha.jpg",
      "projectBy": "Crua Outdoors",
      "projectDescrition": "Lightweight Hiking Tent + Insulated Cocoon + Air-Framed Living Space: Use individually or together for the ultimate outdoors experience",
      "projectLocation": " New York, NY",
          "videoUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/hHMqkmIvOFw"

    },
    {
      "projectID": "00002",
      "projectName": "Two tent system",
      "profileProjectImage": "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.br.catarse/uploads/project/uploaded_image/72644/project_thumb_large_capinha.jpg",
      "projectBy": "Crua Outdoors",
      "projectDescrition": "Lightweight Hiking Tent + Insulated Cocoon + Air-Framed Living Space: Use individually or together for the ultimate outdoors experience",
        "projectLocation": " New York, NY",
        "videoUrl": "hiii"
    },
    {
      "projectID": "00003",
      "projectName": "Three tent system",
      "profileProjectImage": "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.br.catarse/uploads/project/uploaded_image/72644/project_thumb_large_capinha.jpg",
      "projectBy": "Crua Outdoors",
      "projectDescrition": "Lightweight Hiking Tent + Insulated Cocoon + Air-Framed Living Space: Use individually or together for the ultimate outdoors experience",
        "projectLocation": " New York, NY",
        "videoUrl": "hiii"
    }
  ]
}
export default CardData;
```

ProjectDetailPage.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import App from '../HomePopularCards/ProjectCardContainer';
import CardData from '../HomePopularCards/CardData';
export default function ProjectDetailPage(props) {
    const projectID = props.match.params.projectID;
    const project = CardData.cards.find(card => card.projectID === projectID);

    return (
        <div>
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <h2 className="text-center">{project.projectName}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>      

        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                   <div className="col-md-6">
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src={project.videoUrl} ></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        {project.projectBy}
                        {project.projectDescrition}
                        {project.projectLocation}

                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>   
            </div>

    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Main reason Iframe was not loading because there were two files, **CardData.tsx** and **CardData.js** both were present in same directory.Since webpack compiles or gives precedence to CardData.js and I was making changes in **CardData.js**. I simply deleted my **CardData.js** and everything worked !!